# Dynamic search function for UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, string, function, swift, search

I'm trying to create a search function for my table view, but when I type in the second character in my text field, the function crashes. 
I can type in the first character, delete it, and type in a new one and it doesn't crash.

My error says:

> fatal error: can not increment endIndex

and my code looks like this:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    self.loadSearchData(textField.text)
}

func loadSearchData(searchString:String){

    var arrayOfSearches: [String] = []
    let index = count(searchString)

    for company in self.companies{
        let searchIndex = advance(company.startIndex, index)
        if searchString == company.substringToIndex(searchIndex){
        arrayOfSearches.append(company)
        }
    }
    self.companiesToDisplay = arrayOfSearches
    self.companiesTV.reloadData()
}
```

where my `companiesToDisplay` is the array being displayed by my table view.

I know the fault is in my `let searchIndex = advance(company.startIndex, index)` line but I don't know why it would create an error.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let searchIndex = advance(company.startIndex, index)
```

fails at runtime if `index` is greater than the number of characters
in the string `company`. You could use

```
let searchIndex = advance(company.startIndex, index, company.endIndex)
```

instead, which increments the start index by `index` positions, but not beyond the end of the string.

A simpler solution is to use `hasPrefix`:

```
for company in self.companies {
    if company.hasPrefix(searchString) {
        arrayOfSearches.append(company)
    }
}
```

Or use `rangeOfString` which has options for case-insensitive search:

```
for company in self.companies {
    if company.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch | .AnchoredSearch) != nil {
        arrayOfSearches.append(company)
    }
}
```

Comment: jinx, you owe me a soda :)

Comment: The new searchIndex and the for-loop both works, but if I use the .lowercaseString on the strings I compare it crashes, do you know why this is?

Comment: @frank21: OK, fine. But instead of .lowercaseString you can do a case-insensitive comparison, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to replace your `for` loop with this:

```
for company in companies {
    if company.hasPrefix(searchString) {
        arrayOfSearches.append(company)
    }
}
```

That way you aren't messing with `String.Index` which will throw all kinds of errors if you go out of bounds.

You might also consider filtering as an alternative... it is safer, cleaner, and shorter:

```
func loadSearchData(searchString:String) {

    self.companiesToDisplay = self.companies.filter { $0.hasPrefix(searchString) }
    self.companiesTV.reloadData()
}
```

Something like that ought to work, but if it conflicts with something else in your code, post a comment.